# Why Pentaho switch case doesn't break after run the case?

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle, data-integration

i built switch case in `Pentaho` to run predetermined case for varying parameter value.

the problem is `Pentaho` don't break after execution the `case`. so it run all cases! not only the required case.

i attached example of switch case for output text files.

when i run the `Transform`. the switch case run all cases without any break. and it output the three text files !.

[image]

so what i do to solve these problem? i know that `Pentaho Transfrom` run in `Parallel`, but why it doesn't break the switch case !?

This is the `.ktr` file contents:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transformation>
  <info>
    <name>trans</name>
    <description/>
    <extended_description/>
    <trans_version/>
    <trans_type>Normal</trans_type>
    <trans_status>0</trans_status>
    <directory>&#x2f;</directory>
    <parameters>
        <parameter>
            <name>var</name>
            <default_value/>
            <description/>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
    <log>
<trans-log-table><connection/>
<schema/>
<table/>
<size_limit_lines/>
<interval/>
<timeout_days/>
<field><id>ID_BATCH</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ID_BATCH</name></field><field><id>CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>CHANNEL_ID</name></field><field><id>TRANSNAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>TRANSNAME</name></field><field><id>STATUS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STATUS</name></field><field><id>LINES_READ</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_READ</name><subject/></field><field><id>LINES_WRITTEN</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_WRITTEN</name><subject/></field><field><id>LINES_UPDATED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_UPDATED</name><subject/></field><field><id>LINES_INPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_INPUT</name><subject/></field><field><id>LINES_OUTPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_OUTPUT</name><subject/></field><field><id>LINES_REJECTED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_REJECTED</name><subject/></field><field><id>ERRORS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ERRORS</name></field><field><id>STARTDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STARTDATE</name></field><field><id>ENDDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ENDDATE</name></field><field><id>LOGDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOGDATE</name></field><field><id>DEPDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>DEPDATE</name></field><field><id>REPLAYDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>REPLAYDATE</name></field><field><id>LOG_FIELD</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOG_FIELD</name></field><field><id>EXECUTING_SERVER</id><enabled>N</enabled><name>EXECUTING_SERVER</name></field><field><id>EXECUTING_USER</id><enabled>N</enabled><name>EXECUTING_USER</name></field><field><id>CLIENT</id><enabled>N</enabled><name>CLIENT</name></field></trans-log-table>
<perf-log-table><connection/>
<schema/>
<table/>
<interval/>
<timeout_days/>
<field><id>ID_BATCH</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ID_BATCH</name></field><field><id>SEQ_NR</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>SEQ_NR</name></field><field><id>LOGDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOGDATE</name></field><field><id>TRANSNAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>TRANSNAME</name></field><field><id>STEPNAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STEPNAME</name></field><field><id>STEP_COPY</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STEP_COPY</name></field><field><id>LINES_READ</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_READ</name></field><field><id>LINES_WRITTEN</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_WRITTEN</name></field><field><id>LINES_UPDATED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_UPDATED</name></field><field><id>LINES_INPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_INPUT</name></field><field><id>LINES_OUTPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_OUTPUT</name></field><field><id>LINES_REJECTED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_REJECTED</name></field><field><id>ERRORS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ERRORS</name></field><field><id>INPUT_BUFFER_ROWS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>INPUT_BUFFER_ROWS</name></field><field><id>OUTPUT_BUFFER_ROWS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>OUTPUT_BUFFER_ROWS</name></field></perf-log-table>
<channel-log-table><connection/>
<schema/>
<table/>
<timeout_days/>
<field><id>ID_BATCH</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ID_BATCH</name></field><field><id>CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>CHANNEL_ID</name></field><field><id>LOG_DATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOG_DATE</name></field><field><id>LOGGING_OBJECT_TYPE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOGGING_OBJECT_TYPE</name></field><field><id>OBJECT_NAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>OBJECT_NAME</name></field><field><id>OBJECT_COPY</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>OBJECT_COPY</name></field><field><id>REPOSITORY_DIRECTORY</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>REPOSITORY_DIRECTORY</name></field><field><id>FILENAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>FILENAME</name></field><field><id>OBJECT_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>OBJECT_ID</name></field><field><id>OBJECT_REVISION</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>OBJECT_REVISION</name></field><field><id>PARENT_CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>PARENT_CHANNEL_ID</name></field><field><id>ROOT_CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ROOT_CHANNEL_ID</name></field></channel-log-table>
<step-log-table><connection/>
<schema/>
<table/>
<timeout_days/>
<field><id>ID_BATCH</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ID_BATCH</name></field><field><id>CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>CHANNEL_ID</name></field><field><id>LOG_DATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOG_DATE</name></field><field><id>TRANSNAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>TRANSNAME</name></field><field><id>STEPNAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STEPNAME</name></field><field><id>STEP_COPY</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STEP_COPY</name></field><field><id>LINES_READ</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_READ</name></field><field><id>LINES_WRITTEN</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_WRITTEN</name></field><field><id>LINES_UPDATED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_UPDATED</name></field><field><id>LINES_INPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_INPUT</name></field><field><id>LINES_OUTPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_OUTPUT</name></field><field><id>LINES_REJECTED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_REJECTED</name></field><field><id>ERRORS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ERRORS</name></field><field><id>LOG_FIELD</id><enabled>N</enabled><name>LOG_FIELD</name></field></step-log-table>
<metrics-log-table><connection/>
<schema/>
<table/>
<timeout_days/>
<field><id>ID_BATCH</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ID_BATCH</name></field><field><id>CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>CHANNEL_ID</name></field><field><id>LOG_DATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOG_DATE</name></field><field><id>METRICS_DATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>METRICS_DATE</name></field><field><id>METRICS_CODE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>METRICS_CODE</name></field><field><id>METRICS_DESCRIPTION</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>METRICS_DESCRIPTION</name></field><field><id>METRICS_SUBJECT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>METRICS_SUBJECT</name></field><field><id>METRICS_TYPE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>METRICS_TYPE</name></field><field><id>METRICS_VALUE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>METRICS_VALUE</name></field></metrics-log-table>
    </log>
    <maxdate>
      <connection/>
      <table/>
      <field/>
      <offset>0.0</offset>
      <maxdiff>0.0</maxdiff>
    </maxdate>
    <size_rowset>10000</size_rowset>
    <sleep_time_empty>50</sleep_time_empty>
    <sleep_time_full>50</sleep_time_full>
    <unique_connections>N</unique_connections>
    <feedback_shown>Y</feedback_shown>
    <feedback_size>50000</feedback_size>
    <using_thread_priorities>Y</using_thread_priorities>
    <shared_objects_file/>
    <capture_step_performance>N</capture_step_performance>
    <step_performance_capturing_delay>1000</step_performance_capturing_delay>
    <step_performance_capturing_size_limit>100</step_performance_capturing_size_limit>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
    <partitionschemas>
    </partitionschemas>
    <slaveservers>
    </slaveservers>
    <clusterschemas>
    </clusterschemas>
  <created_user>-</created_user>
  <created_date>2014&#x2f;07&#x2f;13 12&#x3a;36&#x3a;07.782</created_date>
  <modified_user>-</modified_user>
  <modified_date>2014&#x2f;07&#x2f;13 12&#x3a;36&#x3a;07.782</modified_date>
  </info>
  <notepads>
  </notepads>
  <connection>
    <name>AgileBI</name>
    <server>localhost</server>
    <type>MONETDB</type>
    <access>Native</access>
    <database>pentaho-instaview</database>
    <port>50006</port>
    <username>monetdb</username>
    <password>Encrypted 2be98afc86aa7f2e4cb14a17edb86abd8</password>
    <servername/>
    <data_tablespace/>
    <index_tablespace/>
    <read_only>true</read_only>
    <attributes>
      <attribute><code>EXTRA_OPTION_INFOBRIGHT.characterEncoding</code><attribute>UTF-8</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>EXTRA_OPTION_MYSQL.defaultFetchSize</code><attribute>500</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>EXTRA_OPTION_MYSQL.useCursorFetch</code><attribute>true</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>PORT_NUMBER</code><attribute>50006</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>PRESERVE_RESERVED_WORD_CASE</code><attribute>Y</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>SUPPORTS_BOOLEAN_DATA_TYPE</code><attribute>Y</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>SUPPORTS_TIMESTAMP_DATA_TYPE</code><attribute>Y</attribute></attribute>
    </attributes>
  </connection>
  <order>
  <hop> <from>Switch &#x2f; Case</from><to>Text file output</to><enabled>Y</enabled> </hop>
  <hop> <from>Switch &#x2f; Case</from><to>Text file output 2</to><enabled>Y</enabled> </hop>
  <hop> <from>Switch &#x2f; Case</from><to>Text file output 2 2</to><enabled>Y</enabled> </hop>
  <hop> <from>Text file output</from><to>Dummy &#x28;do nothing&#x29;</to><enabled>Y</enabled> </hop>
  <hop> <from>Generate Rows</from><to>Set field value to a constant</to><enabled>Y</enabled> </hop>
  <hop> <from>Set field value to a constant</from><to>Switch &#x2f; Case</to><enabled>Y</enabled> </hop>
  </order>
  <step>
    <name>Switch &#x2f; Case</name>
    <type>SwitchCase</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
         <partitioning>
           <method>none</method>
           <schema_name/>
           </partitioning>
<fieldname>var</fieldname>
<use_contains>N</use_contains>
<case_value_type>String</case_value_type>
<case_value_format/>
<case_value_decimal/>
<case_value_group/>
<default_target_step/>
<cases><case><value>a</value>
<target_step>Text file output</target_step>
</case><case><value>b</value>
<target_step>Text file output 2</target_step>
</case><case><value>c</value>
<target_step>Text file output 2 2</target_step>
</case></cases>     <cluster_schema/>
 <remotesteps>   <input>   </input>   <output>   </output> </remotesteps>    <GUI>
      <xloc>271</xloc>
      <yloc>99</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Generate Rows</name>
    <type>RowGenerator</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
         <partitioning>
           <method>none</method>
           <schema_name/>
           </partitioning>
    <fields>
      <field>
        <name>var</name>
        <type>String</type>
        <format/>
        <currency/>
        <decimal/>
        <group/>
        <nullif/>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <set_empty_string>N</set_empty_string>
      </field>
    </fields>
    <limit>10</limit>
    <never_ending>N</never_ending>
    <interval_in_ms>5000</interval_in_ms>
    <row_time_field>now</row_time_field>
    <last_time_field>FiveSecondsAgo</last_time_field>
     <cluster_schema/>
 <remotesteps>   <input>   </input>   <output>   </output> </remotesteps>    <GUI>
      <xloc>47</xloc>
      <yloc>97</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Text file output</name>
    <type>TextFileOutput</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>N</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
         <partitioning>
           <method>none</method>
           <schema_name/>
           </partitioning>
    <separator>&#x3b;</separator>
    <enclosure>&#x22;</enclosure>
    <enclosure_forced>N</enclosure_forced>
    <enclosure_fix_disabled>N</enclosure_fix_disabled>
    <header>Y</header>
    <footer>N</footer>
    <format>DOS</format>
    <compression>None</compression>
    <encoding/>
    <endedLine/>
    <fileNameInField>N</fileNameInField>
    <fileNameField/>
    <create_parent_folder>Y</create_parent_folder>
    <file>
      <name>a</name>
      <is_command>N</is_command>
      <servlet_output>N</servlet_output>
      <do_not_open_new_file_init>N</do_not_open_new_file_init>
      <extention>txt</extention>
      <append>N</append>
      <split>N</split>
      <haspartno>N</haspartno>
      <add_date>N</add_date>
      <add_time>N</add_time>
      <SpecifyFormat>N</SpecifyFormat>
      <date_time_format/>
      <add_to_result_filenames>Y</add_to_result_filenames>
      <pad>N</pad>
      <fast_dump>N</fast_dump>
      <splitevery>0</splitevery>
    </file>
    <fields>
    </fields>
     <cluster_schema/>
 <remotesteps>   <input>   </input>   <output>   </output> </remotesteps>    <GUI>
      <xloc>463</xloc>
      <yloc>98</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Text file output 2</name>
    <type>TextFileOutput</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
         <partitioning>
           <method>none</method>
           <schema_name/>
           </partitioning>
    <separator>&#x3b;</separator>
    <enclosure>&#x22;</enclosure>
    <enclosure_forced>N</enclosure_forced>
    <enclosure_fix_disabled>N</enclosure_fix_disabled>
    <header>Y</header>
    <footer>N</footer>
    <format>DOS</format>
    <compression>None</compression>
    <encoding/>
    <endedLine/>
    <fileNameInField>N</fileNameInField>
    <fileNameField/>
    <create_parent_folder>Y</create_parent_folder>
    <file>
      <name>b</name>
      <is_command>N</is_command>
      <servlet_output>N</servlet_output>
      <do_not_open_new_file_init>N</do_not_open_new_file_init>
      <extention>txt</extention>
      <append>N</append>
      <split>N</split>
      <haspartno>N</haspartno>
      <add_date>N</add_date>
      <add_time>N</add_time>
      <SpecifyFormat>N</SpecifyFormat>
      <date_time_format/>
      <add_to_result_filenames>Y</add_to_result_filenames>
      <pad>N</pad>
      <fast_dump>N</fast_dump>
      <splitevery>0</splitevery>
    </file>
    <fields>
    </fields>
     <cluster_schema/>
 <remotesteps>   <input>   </input>   <output>   </output> </remotesteps>    <GUI>
      <xloc>463</xloc>
      <yloc>182</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Text file output 2 2</name>
    <type>TextFileOutput</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
         <partitioning>
           <method>none</method>
           <schema_name/>
           </partitioning>
    <separator>&#x3b;</separator>
    <enclosure>&#x22;</enclosure>
    <enclosure_forced>N</enclosure_forced>
    <enclosure_fix_disabled>N</enclosure_fix_disabled>
    <header>Y</header>
    <footer>N</footer>
    <format>DOS</format>
    <compression>None</compression>
    <encoding/>
    <endedLine/>
    <fileNameInField>N</fileNameInField>
    <fileNameField/>
    <create_parent_folder>Y</create_parent_folder>
    <file>
      <name>c</name>
      <is_command>N</is_command>
      <servlet_output>N</servlet_output>
      <do_not_open_new_file_init>N</do_not_open_new_file_init>
      <extention>txt</extention>
      <append>N</append>
      <split>N</split>
      <haspartno>N</haspartno>
      <add_date>N</add_date>
      <add_time>N</add_time>
      <SpecifyFormat>N</SpecifyFormat>
      <date_time_format/>
      <add_to_result_filenames>Y</add_to_result_filenames>
      <pad>N</pad>
      <fast_dump>N</fast_dump>
      <splitevery>0</splitevery>
    </file>
    <fields>
    </fields>
     <cluster_schema/>
 <remotesteps>   <input>   </input>   <output>   </output> </remotesteps>    <GUI>
      <xloc>463</xloc>
      <yloc>272</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Dummy &#x28;do nothing&#x29;</name>
    <type>Dummy</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
         <partitioning>
           <method>none</method>
           <schema_name/>
           </partitioning>
     <cluster_schema/>
 <remotesteps>   <input>   </input>   <output>   </output> </remotesteps>    <GUI>
      <xloc>694</xloc>
      <yloc>102</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Set field value to a constant</name>
    <type>SetValueConstant</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
         <partitioning>
           <method>none</method>
           <schema_name/>
           </partitioning>
   <usevar>Y</usevar>
    <fields>
      <field>
        <name>var</name>
        <value>&#x24;&#x7b;var&#x7d;</value>
        <mask/>
        <set_empty_string>N</set_empty_string>
        </field>
      </fields>
     <cluster_schema/>
 <remotesteps>   <input>   </input>   <output>   </output> </remotesteps>    <GUI>
      <xloc>147</xloc>
      <yloc>97</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      </GUI>
    </step>

  <step_error_handling>
  </step_error_handling>
   <slave-step-copy-partition-distribution>
</slave-step-copy-partition-distribution>
   <slave_transformation>N</slave_transformation>
<attributes><group><name>DataService</name>
<attribute><key>stepname</key>
<value/>
</attribute><attribute><key>name</key>
<value/>
</attribute></group></attributes>

</transformation>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as they told me in `Pentaho Forums`. that the main job of switch is to send data to different steps.

so i decided to use `Filter rows`. it's more better for conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the problem is the `Switch/Case`. The issue is that, as you say, all steps in a transformation run in parallel. This means all three `Text file output` steps run (initialize) whether they end up getting data or not.

If you don't want them to create a file if they get no data, check the 'Do not create file at start' checkbox in each of the Text file output steps.